# I want to update inputs in verilog

Tags: verilog

I want to implement the following algorithm in verilog. Is there a way to update input in verilog just like c/c++(eg, a=a+i;)

```
a←a + b + 2 · lsw(a) · lsw(b)
d←(d ⊕ a) >>> 32
c←c + d + 2 · lsw(c) · lsw(d)
b←(b ⊕ c) >>> 24
a←a + b + 2 · lsw(a) · lsw(b)
d←(d ⊕ a) >>> 16
c←c + d + 2 · lsw(c) · lsw(d)
d←(b ⊕ c) >>> 63
```

here a,b,c,d are 64 bit ASCII inputs. And lsw(x) is the least significant word of 32 bit."⊕" denotes bit wise XOR and "+" denotes wordwise addition., and >>> denotes right shift operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want the code to execute line by line as in C. You can use blocking statements inside an always statement for this. You will need a clock signal, because of the feedback nature of your signals.

For example,

```
always@ (posedge clk)
begin
a = a+1;
b = b*a;
c = a+b-c;
end
```

The above code will execute line by line, on every positive edge of clock.

And for the operators you require,

lsw(x) - the least significant word of 32 bit can be represented by **x[7:0]** assuming x is defined as [31:0].

"⊕" bit wise XOR  can be represented by **^** operator.

"+" and "." can be represented by **|** and **&** respectively.

right shift can be done by **>>** operator.

Comment: The error I'm facing while implementing the code is if i declare a,b,c,d as reg, how would I assign them values?

Comment: I want to assign 64 bit ascii valuse to a,b,c and d, and update them.

Comment: you can initialize the reg's using the "initial" keyword. this values will be used at the start of the code. But if you want to give the values as inputs, then declare the variables as inout.

Comment: If I initialize them as input, I won't be able to update them.

Comment: use "inout" instead of input or output.

Comment: Using inout is giving me errrors like "Reference to vector wire 'c' is not a legal reg or variable lvalue"

Comment: I am getting lots of errors. If possible can check my code?